# Audio Mixer does not save the volume settings for all programs. How do I fix it ? (Maybe it's a UWP issue?)

Tags: windows, audio

About 5 days ago I re-installed Win10 and I am still in the process of getting my PC back to normal. However I noticed a New bug: Some of the programs do not save the volume setting after closing them. So far I have tested 4 "programs: Firefox, MS Edge did save, while Gears Pop (a game) and "Video Editor" (literally its name. it auto installed so I think it's an MS app) do not save their Mixer settings. Coincidentally I think the later two are UWP while I believe the former two are not.

I must say that I have not done any further test and I also have not manually installed drivers yet since I am still in the process of getting my PC up to speed. I can say however that I did try editing the registry on the path:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore`

That key was already there. I deleted its sub keys. I even made another one on:

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore`

because I saw one solution somewhere where they were suggesting so. But nothing so far.

I mean, is this even a Windows problem ? A lot of "solutions" were basically suggesting that it was a hardware thing and needed divers and change the devices' settings..... but to me it looks like a windows thing. Like, on the first registry path I mention I can see some keys being created for the programs that do save their volume settings.

I am at a loss. I have tasted Many defeats this past week. I don't think I can take another L